# How to accept only numeric value in XtraInputBox and how can I check which button has been clicked?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have this code that fire on click of button:

```
private void btnDown_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XtraInputBoxArgs args = new XtraInputBoxArgs();
    args.Caption = "Quantité";
    args.Prompt = "Entrez la quantité";
    args.DefaultButtonIndex = 0;
    args.DefaultResponse = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(gridView1.FocusedRowHandle, "Quantité Restante");
    var result= XtraInputBox.Show(args);
}
```

I want to accept  numeric value and backspace (prevent user from entring letters and special charcters in TextEdit).
How can I check which button has been clicked?

Answer (score 2):

i get the solution from Dmitry Tor(DevExpress Support)

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextEdit textEdit = new TextEdit();
        textEdit.Properties.Mask.MaskType = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Mask.MaskType.Numeric;

        XtraInputBoxArgs args = new XtraInputBoxArgs();
        args.Caption = "Quantité";
        args.Prompt = "Entrez la quantité";
        args.DefaultButtonIndex = 0;
        args.DefaultResponse = "Test"; 
        args.Editor = textEdit;

        var result =  XtraInputBox.Show(args);
        if (result != null)
            MessageBox.Show("Ok button pressed");
        else
            MessageBox.Show("Cancel button pressed");
    }
```